# Can't find a way to connect mysql to phpmyadmin's database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've used mysql -u root

and then

```
create database 'whatevername'
```

it results in

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.002 sec)
```

but nothing changes, no database added to the phpmyadmin

solutions will very much be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remove phpmyadmin from the equation. Just use the command line. Once you've created the database. Do:

```
show databases;
```

If your database appears in the list then it's been created. In which case you're probably connecting to the wrong database in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: It does create, but I don't know how to connect it to the right one, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

if use root, try Create a new database user:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'P@s$w0rd123!';
```

Log out of MySQL and Log in as the new database user you just created.

```
mysql -u db_user -p
```

Create a new database

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

modify db_name with the actual name you would like to give the database

Comment: It now shows : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY '1234'' at line 1

Comment: work on 10.3.29-MariaDB just check your version mysql

Comment: Found the issue, it's because I'm on mysql's server type with terminal and not mariadb, but it won't allow me to switch to mariadb on mac